# How to assign photo in .java file to an ID in XML file for Android App

Tags: android

Im trying to assign a picture in my .java file to one of my IDs in the xml file. Can anyone show me some code that would help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more info? Do you mean you have made an ImageView in java that you want to assign to an ImageView in the xml?

Comment: Be more specific with what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "a picture in my .java file"? If you are loading a picture dynamically (e.g. from a server while the app is running), then there is no way to reference it in XML, since all the XML files are compiled to resources when the .apk is packaged.

Answer (score 2):

Load the proper resource file using setContentView(R.layout.layout_of_activity)

Then, make an ImageView object and use the findViewById method by passing it the ID of the image that you assigned it from the xml file, i.e.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic_id);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the pic like,

```
picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_png);
```

Try checking out the android api samples to see how to do some more complex image manipulation like animating or rotating